i want to set a horizontal scrollable tabs in flutter
in my screen i have three tabs and i want to the tab start with left center sides here is a image   but it start with some padding with left side
TabBar(
        controller: controller,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        isScrollable: true,
        indicatorColor: indicatorColor,
        indicatorWeight: indicatorWeight,
        labelColor: labelColor,
        unselectedLabelColor: unselectedLabelColor,
        labelStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        tabs: tabs,
      ),


you can refer this article

try to set labelPadding to EdgeInsets.zero

this article can not solve my Problem @ChamalkaGunawardana is any other solutions ?

no it remove the space between the tabs label @Zhentao is any other solution ?

try set tabAlignment to TabAlignment.start
    TabBar(
      controller: controller,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
      isScrollable: true,
      indicatorColor: indicatorColor,
      indicatorWeight: indicatorWeight,
      labelColor: labelColor,
      indicator:const CustomTabIndicator(),
      unselectedLabelColor: unselectedLabelColor,
      labelStyle:TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      tabs: tabs,
    ),

